# Android Arabic Text Concatenation

Tags: android, textview, arabic, typeface, spannable

in Android I would like to concatenate number with Arabic text. but if i concatenate the number then the arabic text direction changes.

Example: My Application reads each line of arabic text from file and adds the line number to each line and appended to string builder , After completion of reading final string will be displayed on text view.

Here is my code

```
SpannableStringBuilder styledString = new SpannableStringBuilder(TextUtils.concat(l,"("+sn+")"));
                styledString.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", type), 0, l.length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
               // styledString.setSpan(new    AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),l.length()-1,l.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannablestringbuilder.append(styledString);
```

Expected Output:
(3) ﺑِﺴْﻢِ ٱﻟﻠَّﻪِ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣْﻤَٰﻦِ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣِﻴِ(1)ٱﻟْﺤَﻤْﺪُ ﻟِﻠَّﻪِ ﺭَﺏِّ ٱﻟْﻌَٰﻠَﻤِﻴﻦَ (2) ٱﻟﺮَّﺣْﻤَٰﻦِ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣِﻴﻢِ

[image]

Actual Output
(1)ﺑِﺴْﻢِ ٱﻟﻠَّﻪِ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣْﻤَٰﻦِ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣِﻴﻢِ (2)ٱﻟْﺤَﻤْﺪُ ﻟِﻠَّﻪِ ﺭَﺏِّ ٱﻟْﻌَٰﻠَﻤِﻴﻦَ ٱﻟﺮَّﺣْﻤَٰﻦِ(3) ٱﻟﺮَّﺣِﻴﻢِ[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Removing spaces
2. Use hyphens `-` instead of spaces
3. Try finding a way to change the direction

By the way, this question is answerde [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884569/spannablestringbuilder-setspan-doesnt-work-on-arabic-text) and might be a duplicate!

Thanks for posting!